# Does breaking gold plating in Phase 1 make Arch Tempered Kulve Taroth leave sooner in Phase 2?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

When I do the siege by myself I can break 4 to 5 pieces of plating in pursuit level 6 during phase 1 but Kulve Taroth ends up leaving the area within 1-2 minutes during phase 2 when I do this. I usually end up breaking the plating off of her horns and then chipping them in phase 1 along with the 4-5 pieces of gold plating, should I wait to do this until I break off all of the plating that I need for her to go into her furied state or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kulve Taroth will escape unless she's been made to dig twice in area 2, by breaking five pieces of her golden mantle. Her horns' gold plating doesn't make any difference.

Comment: do you know why Kulve Taroth leaves faster in phase 2 when i do break plating in phase 1 rather than when I don't break plating in phase 1?

Comment: Probably because you focus on breaking her horn plating instead of her mantle. If you don't break her mantle enough times to make her dig, she'll leave.